# Show that the integers greater than 10 are countably infinite with a bijection from the positive integers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I have a small understanding of what a countably infinite set is, but I don't know how to show a bijection between two sets to prove it.

This is my solution so far:

$S = \{s \in \Bbb Z^+ \mid s > 10 \} $
$f: S \to \Bbb Z^+$

Where do I go from here? How do I show a bijection between these two sets?

Comment: Map $11$ to $1$, $12$ to $2$, $13$ to $3$, $14$ to $4$ ..... should I keep going?

Comment: I suspect you're overthinking the problem.  What's the most obvious $1-1$ map you can think of between the positive integers and the integers greater than $10$?  Is that obvious map surjective?  Because if it's $1-1$ and surjective, then you have your bijection.  And the definition of "countably infinite" that you're probably using says that a set is countably infinite if there's a bijection between that set and the positive integers, so the very existence of that map proves that $S$ is countably infinite.

Comment: Can you start listing the elements of $S$? What's the first element? What's the second element? What's the third element? ... What's the $n^{th}$ element? This *is* the bijection.

Comment: @JackPfaffinger That's not quite right.  $10 \notin S$.

Comment: Thanks Robert, fixed.

Comment: @JackPfaffinger I understand the general concept, but I don't know how you show the mapped elements with discrete math symbols instead of listing specific values one by one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(n)=n+10$ will do nicely as a bijection between the positive integers and positive integers greater than $10$

Comment: So a bijection can be represented as a regular function? Also, the $n$ in this function is $\in \Bbb Z^+$ , right?

Comment: @Al. All correct!  But, please understand that I just gave you a function ... you will still have to show that this function is an actual bijection, i.e. show it is surjective and injective

Comment: I've been looking for a clear guide on how to show a function is surjective/injective, but all of the explanations I've found go over my head because I don't understand discrete mathematics very well... I've spent hours reading the textbook and trying to understand it, without much success. Can you give an example of a function (not related to my original question) and show how it's surjective?

Comment: @Al.  For surjectivity, ask yourself this: is it true that for every element in the co-domain, there is some number in the domain that maps to it? So, in this case, if I pick an element from $S$ (say, $47$), is there an element in the set of positive integers that maps to this element?  Will you be able to find such a positive integer for each positive integer greater than $10$?  And for injectivity, you have to show that there are no two different positive integers that get mapped to the very same positive integer greater than $10$